# How to route from Ubuntu server with two ISP connections?

Tags: linux, routing, wide-area-network

At the office we have a server with a single `$SERVER_IF` having a local IP address `$SERVER_IP_MAIN=192.168.1.12/24` behind an ADSL router `$ROUTER_MAIN` with a static external IP address from `$ISP_MAIN`. Everything works fine, incoming and outgoing connections pass through without any issues.

Now, we got another connection to a different `$ISP_BACKUP` for fallback purposes using `$ROUTER_BACKUP`. **I don't need any load balancing**; all outgoing connections should still go through `$ISP_MAIN`, I just want to ensure that any incoming connections through `$ISP_BACKUP` are routed through `$ROUTER_BACKUP`.

I tried to follow some generic advice using `ip route` and `ip rule`, but I must be doing something wrong. (My main source: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html )

The current setup is as follows:

```
server has:
    $SERVER_IF=eth0 with address $SERVER_IP_MAIN=192.168.1.12/24
    $SERVER_IF:0=eth0:0 with address $SERVER_IP_BACKUP=192.168.252.12/24 # pseudo interface

$ROUTER_MAIN has:
    $ROUTER_MAIN_IP=192.168.1.254/24

$ROUTER_BACKUP has:
    $ROUTER_BACKUP_IP=192.168.252.1/24
```

Using `tcpdump` on the server, I verified that `$ROUTER_BACKUP` is set-up correctly since packets coming through `$ISP_BACKUP` are being delivered to `$SERVER_IP_BACKUP`, but I assume that the replies are being routed through `$ISP_MAIN` because I can't establish a connection from an external server:

```
12:54:06.950853 IP 178.128.57.39.dsl.dyn.forthnet.gr.57987 > 192.168.252.12.5631: Flags [S], seq 2240370501, win 5840, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 471912856 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
12:54:06.950903 IP 192.168.252.12.5631 > 178.128.57.39.dsl.dyn.forthnet.gr.57987: Flags [S.], seq 2209117020, ack 2240370502, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 215023497 ecr 471912556,nop,wscale 4], length 0
```

Note that `$ROUTER_BACKUP` does not do a SNAT, since the server receives packets with the original outside-world source IP address.

How can I implement what is needed? (i.e. connections through `$ISP_BACKUP` to be routed through `$ROUTER_BACKUP`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, given the setup, all was needed was to:

- add a table named `backup` in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`
- `ip route add 192.168.252.0/24 dev eth0:0 src 192.168.252.12 table backup` (local network for fallback purposes)
- `ip route add default via 192.168.252.1 table backup` (its default route)
- `ip rule add from 192.168.252.12 lookup backup` (use it when replying from `$SERVER_IP_BACKUP`)

I must have somehow botched that final line earlier.

After all of the above:

- `ip route flush table cache`